# ASP.NET Response.Redirect no funciona

Tags: android, asp.net, visual-studio, redirección

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un POS en el que requiero mandar por url los siguientes parametros:

- monto
- referencia de transaccion (se genera automaticamente según el consecutivo del ticket)
- correo del cliente

[image: Pantalla de captura de monto y correo]

Una vez que el vendedor le da clic al botón Pagar, **sucede lo siguiente:**

```
string ticketNum = genTicketNumber();
    if(ticketNum != "")
        Response.Redirect(Constantes.Paginas.Carrito + "?" + montoPago+ "=" + referenciaVta+"="+txtemail.Text);
```

Pero cuando le doy clic, en la **URL** no veo que haya cambiado y sigue mostrando la **url** original

> http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx

El problema esta en que, antes si lo hacia, sin embargo desde que repartí todo el carrito en un control Multiview, ya no funciona la re-dirección con el "?" y únicamente funciona si uso una diagonal "/"  o sea:

Funciona

> http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx/1600=idTicket=correo@cliente.com

No funciona

> http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx?1600=idTicket-01=correo@cliente.com

**EDIT**
la re-dirección la utilizo para poder decirle a mi app de android cuando deba de enviar al activity donde se realiza el cobro. Aquí dejo el código del webView donde valido eso.

```
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carga Finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
            if(url.contains("sendScanReader"))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Scan.class);
                //pd.dismiss();
                startActivityForResult(i,100);

            }else if(url.contains("vta")){
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(url,"/");
                String first = tokens.nextToken();
                String second = tokens.nextToken();

                StringTokenizer tokenValues = new StringTokenizer(second,"=");
                //total a pagar durante la transaccion
                String ttlPago = tokenValues.nextToken();
                // referencia
                String reference = tokenValues.nextToken();
                reference = reference.replace("_","/");
                // email
                String email = tokenValues.nextToken();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Payment.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("ttlPago",ttlPago);
                i.putExtra("vtaRef",reference);
                i.putExtra("correo",email);
                //view.loadUrl(Common.getHomeURL());
                //pd.dismiss();
                startActivityForResult(i,100);
            }
            else{
                if(pd.isShowing())
                    pd.dismiss();
                Common.setURL(url);
            }
            if(pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pasa que cuando usas el "/" es como si enviaras a una página mas y va a acceder sin mas, lo que yo veo y sospecho que es tu problema es que no estas asignando ninguna variable donde almacenar los parámetros que quieres enviar. Prueba de esta forma.

```
Response.Redirect(Constantes.Paginas.Carrito + "?montoPago=" + montoPago+ "&referenciaVta=" + referenciaVta + "&email=" + txtemail.Text.ToString());
```

Ya a la hora de consumir tus parámetros lo haces así:

```
Request.QueryString["montoPago"].ToString();
```

Comment: Es que el problema es que si uso el ? el resto del texto nunca se queda en el url, y la url siempre termina siendo `http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx` y el codigo del postback donde valido que contenga "?"  siempre me arroja falso

Comment: Probaste lo que te dije? En todo caso si aun persiste el problema tambien puedes usar cookies o variables de sesión:  Session["email"] = txtemail.Text.ToString();

Comment: la re-dirección la utilizo para poder decirle a mi app de android cuando deba de enviar al activity donde se realiza el cobro. Como te comento, usando el **?** la url no muestra los parámetros y por lo tanto el onPageFinished de mi app no funciona como debería

Answer (score 0):

Mencionas que usas el URL

```
http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx?1600=idTicket-01=correo@cliente.com
```

¿No están al revés la asignaciones?, me parece que el URL no tiene el formato correcto

```
http://localhost:48789/CarritoDetalle.aspx?idTicket=1600&email=correo@cliente.com
```

Comment: "Las respuesas no deben usarse para aclaraciones sobre la pregunta". Revisar [answer].

Comment: No, despues del simbolo ? todo lo que esta son parametros. 1600(monto de compra)=idticket-01(referencia de venta)=correo@cliente.com(email del cliente para su voucher)

Comment: Intenta utilizar en tu aplicación android la Clase uri String chapter = uri.getQueryParameter("idticket"); para obtener el valor del idticket usando la estructura que te mencionaba arriba